# How can I run same command in a shell every 3h

Tags: php, linux, bash, testing, behat

I have a bunch of Behat test scenarios, about 3000, these take about 3h to run, and I have deducated machine to run these, so looking for a command which would trigger this command:

```
./behat --tags oxi --profile staging --format custom
```

Every 3h. Is there any way to do this?

I looked at  "watch" command but even if I do run it:

```
watch -n 10800 ./behat...
```

the watch for some reason is running it every 4294 seconds. Not 10800 which I stated in command. So is there any other way of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First move the command to it's own script `vi /usr/local/bin/dowatch`:

```
#!/bin/bash
./behat --tags oxi --profile staging --format custom
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dowatch
```

Cron seems like a good choice for scheduling... in the shell:

```
crontab -e
```

Then edit the source to:

```
* */3 * * * /usr/local/bin/dowatch
```

Which says any minute (first) every three hours (second) any day of the month (third) any month (fourth) any day of the week (fifth) execute `/usr/local/bin/dowatch`

Comment: The `watch -n 10800` part, if i'm reading the question correctly, was an attempt to get things to happen every 3 hours.  The job script probably shouldn't include it.